# Complete CSS rule as variable in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, less

i am used to work with Less... and, due to the fact
the Scss has become more popular I am now switching to Scss

**In Less I used do this:**

```
.cFF {color: #fff;}
.c00 {color: #000;}

.example a {.cFF:)
```

I am trying to find a way to use a complete CSS value as a variable
I know I can just use the color.

Couldn't find how to do that in Scss... what am I missing?

Comment: You cannot reuse class declarations in SCSS like you can in Less. Use mixins instead. Consider stopping to use a preprocessor and instead start making use of CSS custom properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the color classes as `mixins` and then `include` them in the other class:

```
@mixin cFF {color: #fff;}
@mixin c00 {color: #000;}

.example a {
  @include cFF;
}
```

[More Info](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

Comment: i guess that is good for long declarations but for shorthand its just the as simply writing it. Anyhow - thanks for the descriptive answer.

Comment: Ok, since i dont see any other way / solution which was submitted here one I could found in sass docs I approve this answer. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$color: #912313;

.class{
   color: $color;
}
```

Comment: I think that's what OP meant with "I know I can just the color."

Comment: So yeah - mixin is the solution for you